# How do you create Windows RDP Style border in CSS?

Tags: css, border-radius

So, I was going thru this [Dribble Shot](https://dribbble.com/shots/23210297-Fintech-Landing-Page-Design) and was intrigued how it can be made. I tried all sorts of border-radius tricks but couldn't reach much further :(.

It seems like there is a S shaped border that is skewed but I dont know how to make it. Even chat GPT wont understand what I want to make.

Any help?
TIA

I have tried my best to use border-left & right radius css but did not get the results.